# ScriptLink without Locale ID in path

Tags: localization, javascript, master-page

I have this `ScriptLink` in my custom Master Page:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="my.js" runat="server"/>
```

**This renders as `1033/my.js` on an English Site Collection, but as `1053/my.js` on a Swedish Site Collection.** I've installed the SharePoint 2010 Server Language Pack, and when creating a new Site Collection, apparently there is the option to create it in Swedish.

This JavaScript file is not localized, and with this path I'd need to deploy the script to the 14 Hive once for each installed language. And that just feels like the wrong solution.

Is `ScriptLink` the wrong choice here, or how are you supposed to solve this? Perhaps I am not supposed to deploy it to the 14 Hive at all, but if so, what are the feasible alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the attribute Localizable="False".  It would look like this :

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink Language="javascript" Name="my.js" Localizable="False" runat="server"/>
```